# problem of html video operational with netfront browser 4.1 : aspx

Tags: html5-video

for my project, i want to embedded an html video tag in aspx page. this tag is operational on edge, google chrome and firefox but it's not operational on old mobile phone with "netfront browser 4.1 by power access" ; there is nothing, the htlml video tag doesn't appear. have you got a solution to embed this html video tag or to embed an other type of video tag on old mobile phones.

the following code is :

thanks you for your contribution.

M.A.

Comment: Isn't that browser from around year 2010? Did HTML5 video support exist back then? Have you ever watched a website's video using that browser? From research I personally don't think web video is possible on that browser, maybe offer a "Download this video" link for users who cannot play in-browser (they can play the MP4 elsewhere).

Comment: hello, the version of netfront browser 4.1 is launched in 2011. i'm trying to play a video with www.youtube.com site and the video don't play too. i don't want to put a download link because the site offers the abilitie to see video or audio files by a list. i'm sure there is certainly an abilitie to embed html5 video or an other video tag. thanks you for your contribution.